# Can I use PayPal chained payments in HTML5 webapp

Tags: html, paypal, chained

I've found the client apis for iOS, Android, RIM but want to develop a webapp and phonegap it. I've seen their web version with embedded payments but when you  login it opens a browser to open paypal so we lose the app.

Thanks

Adam